# Trying to save array elements into .txt file MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32

I'm making a program in MIPS that asks the user for the size of the array and right after it asks for n integers, so I make a bubblesort to order the data, but I need to save the highest and lowest value of that array and then save each element of the array inside a .txt file, if you can help me i'll appreciate it alot :D !

***[Screenshoot of the run console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkArK.png)***

***CODE:***

```
data
    array: .space 100   
    size: .asciiz "Enter size: "
int: .asciiz "Enter int: "
final: .asciiz "\nSorted: "

.text

main:

la $a0,size                       
li $v0,4
syscall

li $v0,5
syscall

move $s1, $v0                      
sub $s1,$s1,1                       

addint:

la $a0,int                     
li $v0,4
syscall

li $v0,5        
syscall

move $t3,$v0                        
add $t1,$zero,$zero                 
sll $t1,$t0,2                       

sw $t3,array ( $t1 )                
addi $t0,$t0,1                      
slt $t1,$s1,$t0                     
beq $t1,$zero,addint                

la $a0,array                        
addi $a1,$s1,1                      

jal bubble_sort                            

la $a0,final 
li $v0,4
syscall

la $t0,array                        
li $t1,0                            

print:
lw $a0,0($t0)                       
li $v0,1
syscall

addi $t0,$t0,4                      
addi $t1,$t1,1                      
slt $t2,$s1,$t1                     
beq $t2,$zero,print                 

li $v0,10                           
syscall

bubble_sort:
li $t0,0                            

loop1:

addi $t0,$t0,1                      
bgt $t0,$a1,end                  
add $t1,$a1,$zero                   

loop2:

bge $t0,$t1,loop1                  

subi $t1,$t1,1                      

sll $t4, $t1, 2                     
subi $t3, $t4, 4                    

add $t4,$t4,$a0                     
add $t3,$t3,$a0                     
lw $t5,0($t4)
lw $t6,0($t3)

swap:
bgt $t5,$t6,loop2                   
sw $t5,0($t3)                       
sw $t6,0($t4)
j loop2

end:
jr $ra
```

Comment: Help you how?  Your input and sorting code work, right?  Are you just asking how to print to a file instead of to standard output?  I think the MARS system calls (https://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/Help/SyscallHelp.html) only include file output via an fwrite equivalent, so you'll have to format and convert integers into text strings yourself.  So do that...

Comment: i would like to create 2 words (highest and lowest) then save the highest and lowest number of the array in those variables then print them too.

Comment: Ok, so loop over the array and find them, then print those 2 registers.  Or update min/max while reading input.  You already know how to compare numbers to implement bubble sort.  (No need to store min/max in memory, MIPS has lots of registers)